# How change TextDecorations as Strikethrough?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagridview, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to change inactive data with strikethrough decoration.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="{Binding SelectedEntryType.TypeOfEntry, Converter={StaticResource DisplayValueToStrikethrough}}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

The problem is the following: `The member "TextDecorations" is not recognized or is not accessible.`
I'm using MVVM design pattern.
I already added the System.Windows dll. How can I fix this error? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try write `TextBlock.TextDecorations` like this:

```
<Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" 
        Value="{Binding SelectedEntryType.TypeOfEntry, Converter={StaticResource DisplayValueToStrikethrough}}" />
```

*`Edit`*

In this case, you need to implement `DataGridTemplateColumn` with `TextBlock` or use *`ElementStyle`* for `DataGridTextColumn`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Test">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Strikethrough" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: i try with TextBlock.TextDecorations but not work. i think reason is i didn't use TextBlock inside the grid. i am using <DataGridTextColumn> and  <DataGridComboBoxColumn> only.

Comment: or may be the problem with TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

Comment: thanks nikolaev. i try this one its working :) But for still<DataGridComboBoxColumn> not apper. :(